# 403 error code on google maps imagery

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps, applet

Working on a basic map using UnfoldingMaps Library and Eclipse. It's for educational purposes(taking a course for OOP Java), and when trying to access the google map provider using map object:

```
AbstractMapProvider provider = new Google.GoogleProvider();
```

use then the `draw()` method to create the map.I run the applet(on eclipse) and it runs for the first time. But after I ran it the second time, it starts giving me the following error:

```
Unfolding Map v0.9.7 (UCSD edition)
Using OpenGLMapDisplay with processing.opengl.PGraphics2D
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@116&hl=de&x=180&y=414&z=10&s=Galileo
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:91)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1466)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1464)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1463)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
at processing.core.PApplet.createInputRaw(PApplet.java:7267)
at processing.core.PApplet.createInput(PApplet.java:7235)
at processing.core.PApplet.loadBytes(PApplet.java:7462)
at processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(PApplet.java:5879)
at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.getTileFromUrl(Unknown Source)
at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
The file "http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@116&hl=de&x=180&y=414&z=10&s=Galileo" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
```

Possible causes I read online:

1.6 java compiler security concerns
trying to access tiles abuses terms of service with google API(really not super aware of the terms and since it's  my first map, not sure the tiles how they are accessed)
multiple requests over the limit(not possible in my case as the second time I run the applet, it starts giving me the error)

I'm just trying to find a way if possible to use the google map provider for my project. I would not like to use other providers(such as Microsoft)as google's in my perspective is more complete.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are using **more than one object** to provide the map in your code, example: 
AbstractMapProvider provider1 = new Google.GoogleTerrainProvider(); 
AbstractMapProvider provider2 = new Google.GoogleTerrainProvider(); 
Instead, **use just one object provider** in your whole code, and then reset your device ip address, or restart your router, because google won't allow the ip address to use the provider even after fixing your code due to the abuse of the service terms.
that will fix the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may have exceeded the number of allowed queries to Google for the day. You can use use an alternative map(http://unfoldingmaps.org/javadoc/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/providers/package-summary.html) provider or work offline if this happens.You have reported that you will only be blocked for 24 hours from google so you can restore using the provider at that time.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it was not the allowed queries. I only made 2 request and on the third one, it automtically blocked it. Waited 24 hours later, unblocked ip, but made 1 request and it was fine. The second one it blocked it again. Had to use a different map provider, but I wanted to use the google provider as the imagery is much better, but I guess theres a problem with the way the unfolding maps library requests thet tiles from the google provider.